# data.table. Fast way to count number of changes within every column

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to know how many times each variable changes within each group and later add the result for all groups.

I've found this way:

```
mi[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x != shift(x), 
  na.rm=T) ), by = ID][,-1][,lapply(.SD,sum, na.rm=T)]
```

It works, it produces the proper result but it's really slow in my large datatable.
I would like to do both operations inside the same lapply (or something faster and more compact), but the first one is done by group, the second isn't.

It could be written in an easier way (maybe not always)

```
mi[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x != shift(x), 
    na.rm=T) )] [,-1]-mi[,length(unique(ID))]+1
```

But it's still slow and needs a lot of memory.

Any other idea?

I've also tried with diffs instead of shift, but it becomes more difficult.

Here you have a dummy example:

```
mi <- data.table(ID=rep(1:3,each=4) , year=rep(1:4, times=3),
   VREP=rep(1:3,each=4) , VDI=rep(1:4, times=3), RAN=sample(12))
mi <- rbind(mi, data.table(4,1,1,1,0), use.names=F)
```

Big example for benchmark

```
mi <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(0:100,10000000,
 replace=T), nrow=100000, ncol=100))
mi[,ID := rep(1:1000,each=100)]
```

My problem is that the true dataset is much bigger, it's in the limit of memory size, then I've configured R to be able to use more memory using the pagefile, and it makes many operations slow.
I know I could do it splitting the file and joining it again, but sometimes that makes things more difficult or some operations are not splittable.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, having ordered by "ID", you could count the number of times a change in values goes along with a non-change in id; `id = mi$ID[-1] == mi$ID[-nrow(mi)]; sapply(mi, function(x) sum((x[-1] != x[-length(x)]) & id))`

Comment: I'm sorry to say your method is two times slower than my first method and four times slower than the second.

Comment: Benchmark and suitably large example (written as a function of `n`) needed...

Comment: With the new data.table my benhcmkark is:  method1 1.35sec, method2 0.092sec, alexis 0.30sec

Comment: @skan: From your two answers, I had to remove the `[, -1]` because I could not get it to work otherwise -- it seems it has to do with how `"[.data.table"` works, unless I have an outdated version. Other than that, your "method2" is indeed faster, but (at least regarding your large dataset) it does not seem to return the same results as "method1" and mine (which return the same result).

Comment: @skan your 2nd method produces incorrect results - it assumes that the numbers will be different on each boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second method produces incorrect results, so is not a fair comparison point. Here's an optimized version of alexis_laz's suggestion instead:

```
setorder(mi, ID)
setDT(Map(`!=`, mi, shift(mi)))[,
  lapply(lapply(.SD, `&`, !ID), sum, na.rm = T), .SDcols = -"ID"]
#   year VREP VDI RAN
#1:    9    0   9   9
```

On your bigger sample:

```
setorder(mi, ID)
microbenchmark(method1(), alexis_laz(), eddi(), times = 5)
#Unit: milliseconds
#         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#    method1() 7336.1830 7510.9543 7932.0476 8150.3197 8207.2181 8455.563     5
# alexis_laz() 1350.0338 1492.3793 1509.0790 1492.5426 1577.3318 1633.107     5
#       eddi()  400.3999  475.6908  494.5805  504.6163  524.2077  567.988     5
```

Comment: Could you explain the Map, please?

Comment: it basically does the same as `mi != shift(mi)`, except it keeps the list structure instead of converting to a matrix which saves a lot of time

Comment: I've tried it and with my database is 60 times faster.

Comment: Could you also explain why you use "`&`, !ID" and my method doesn't need it?

Comment: @skan because you do it by `ID`, so are automatically aware of the boundaries between them, while this is done for the entire columns and figures out the boundaries by keeping track of `ID` change (same idea as @alexis_laz)

Comment: That's nice. Was trying to figure out why the difference in timing and the (main) thing that seems to speed it up is the avoidance of the double negative subsetting (which has to pass many transformations until the actual subsetting) -- `x = sample(1e6); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(x[-1] != x[-length(x)], x != shift(x))`. Not sure, though, if anything else adds to the difference. Also, evaluating 1 closure VS >1 primitives does not seem to have differences in efficiency as far as I can tell.

Comment: alexis uses & ID but you use !ID in your lapply(.SD, `&`, !ID)

Comment: he also has an equality vs the inequality here